# UIView not Showing in Main View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Hi all I'm implementing in my main `ViewController` some `UIView` custom class .. All are shown but only the `KPHomeInfluenceUser` is not visible .. Definitely it is a stupid question or lack of attention but you can explain why you do not see it ?? What am I doing is a wrong way to implement `UIView` Custom Class? If my method is wrong you can describe the correct method? I've seen many programmers implement classes this way.... Excuse me for stupid question

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self scrollView];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.calendar clearAllDataToHomeCalendarAndReloadData];
    [self.calendar scrollHomeCalendarToCurrentDayAndMonth];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (!_scrollView) {
        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];

        [self.scrollView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;
        [self.scrollView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
        [self.scrollView.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor].active = YES;
        [self.scrollView.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor].active = YES;

        [self calendar];
        [self influenceUser];
        [self homeBottom];
    }
    return _scrollView;
}

-(KPHomeCalendar *)calendar {
    if (!_calendar) {
        _calendar = [[KPHomeCalendar alloc] init];
        _calendar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.calendar];

        [self.calendar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.baseUserPhoto.topAnchor constant:-5].active = YES;
        [self.calendar.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.baseUserPhoto.rightAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
        [self.calendar.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor constant:-10].active = YES;
        [self.calendar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:85].active = YES;
    }
    return _calendar;
}

-(KPHomeInfluenceUser *)influenceUser {
    KPHomeInfluenceUser *influence = [[KPHomeInfluenceUser alloc] init];
    influence.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:influence];

    [influence.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.calendar.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
    [influence.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.scrollView.leftAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
    [influence.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.scrollView.rightAnchor constant:-10].active = YES;
    [influence.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:100].active = YES;

    return influence;
}
```